# Php code works on guest os but doesn't work on host os

Tags: php, virtual-machine

Can you give me some guide on how to determine whats the problem if the same piece of code works on guest os. And doesn't work on the host os? 
I've created the project on Windows 7 but now it seems to be working on XP only.
Here's what I have installed on the host os(Windows 7):
[image]

And here's what I got on the guest os:
[image]

And here's the screenshot. The guest os and host os side by side:
[image]

Other things which are the same:

- php version
- mysql version
- apache
- same data stored on the database

Here's the code of checkout.php:
http://cu.pastebin.com/YeBR9rTs
Forgive me if its messy.

Comment: Is the data this populates from present on both? Is there any GET params in the second address bar? Can you post code of `checkout.php`?

Comment: I have a feeling that maybe a program that I have installed is conflicting with php. That's why I also posted the applications which are installed on the host and on the guest.

Comment: @everybody who tried to help: thanks, it appears that one of these chrome extensions are interfering with my program: chrome sniffer, session manager, ultimate chrome flag, wot, web technology notifier. I disable them all and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All seems to be related to your pulling info from $_GET.  The error on line 65 doesn't find $_GET['ids'], which leads to the foreach error on line 86 which uses the variable set by $_GET['ids'] as an arguement.  Then on line 355 you're pulling $_GET['ini_pay'] on line 124 as $initpay.  So, for some reason, either the $_GET superglobal isn't being populated, or the link that goes to the page is malformed and doesn't include the `?ids=x&ini_pay=y` stuff.

Post the `phpinfo();` information from the host server.

Comment: Looks like you tested $_GET to call it by setting `?phpinfo=1` and running `phpinfo();` if true, so $_GET seems to be populating correctly, which leaves the address itself.  Are you sure that when you go to checkout.php on the host machine you had the full line of $_GET information in the address?

Comment: yup, its the same. I do not really know why its acting that way. All of the scripts which uses dompdf acts that way while on the host os. But everything seems to be fine on the guest os.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that the machine that it isn't working on has the error level set to E_STRICT, try adding the following line to the beginning and see if it starts working.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
```